# Angular - Remove mat-expansion-panel border & box-shadow

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way to remove the border, I think it's the `box-shadow` of a `mat-expansion-panel` from Angular Material? I want it to be all white, so you only would see Text and expansion arrow

```html
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel class="" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                   (closed)="panelOpenState = false">

   <mat-expansion-panel-header>

     <mat-panel-title>
       <span class="right">Filter</span>
     </mat-panel-title>

   </mat-expansion-panel-header>

   <p><app-data></app-data></p>

 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

[image: Mat-Panel]

Comment: Take a look at the [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), and remove it with CSS

Answer (score 107):

add `mat-elevation-z0` class. Works like a charm, I needed to use that recently.

```
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                   (closed)="panelOpenState = false">

   <mat-expansion-panel-header>

     <mat-panel-title>
       <span class="right">Filter</span>
     </mat-panel-title>

   </mat-expansion-panel-header>

   <p><app-data></app-data></p>

 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: @Sergi Sadly i don't know. Try to inspect styles with DevTools

Comment: To remove hover style 

`.mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expanded) .mat-expansion-panel-header:not([aria-disabled='true']):hover {
  background: white;
}`

Comment: Using angular material, this is the perfect way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

I do it with css:

```
.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*='mat-elevation-z']) {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Easy & short. Couldn't be any better!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, You can remove box-shadow and border:
Just Put in CSS or SCSS (Real-time work)

```
.mat-expansion-panel{
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*='mat-elevation-z']) {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); 
}
```

This will do.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the default `border-radius` you might to override the default `border-radius` values which you can find inspecting `mat-expansion-panel` in the browser inspector.

[image]

As you can see `.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:last-of-type` and `.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:first-of-type` sets the 4px `border-radius`

`border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;`
`border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;`

`border-top-right-radius: 4px;`
`border-top-left-radius: 4px;`

The below solution helps to precise override those values:

```
.mat-accordion {
    & > .mat-expansion-panel {
      &:first-of-type,
      &:last-of-type {
        border-radius: unset;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can as well toggle the class *mat-expansion-panel* by doing

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-expansion-panel]="false">
     ...
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: This solution removes the shadow, but also disables the animations.